# Mock method called inside testing method in same class

Tags: android, mockito, junit4

```
 public class MyClass {

   public int result(){
     int result = calculate(new ValueProvider());
          return result;
      }

   public int calculate(ValueProvider provider){
            return provider.getSalary();
      }

}

public class ValueProvider {

    public int getSalary(){
        return 10000000;
    }
}
```

I need to test method `result()`, but have to mock second method calculate which should return default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Mockito `spy` to create a partial mock.

For example:

```
public class TestMyClass {

    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        MyClass spy = Mockito.spy(MyClass.class);

        // this will cause MyClass.calculate() to return 5 when it 
        // is invoked with *any* instance of ValueProvider
        Mockito.doReturn(5).when(spy).calculate(Mockito.any(ValueProvider.class));

        Assert.assertEquals(123, spy.result());
    }
}
```

In this test case the invocation on `calculate` is mocked but the invocation on `result` is real. From [the docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13):

> You can create spies of real objects. When you use the spy then the real methods are called (unless a method was stubbed).

Comment: not as expected, it return with its calculated value not 5

Comment: That suggests that it has not been able to match on `new ValueProvider()`, I have no idea how the ValueProvider's equals method is implemented. You'll know this since it is your class so perhaps use a different matcher when setting up the expectation on `caluclate()`.

Comment: i added valueProvider code in the question, now you can understand.